# How to emulate the curves and color of the video?

Tags: graphics, color, syntax, animation, video

I found this animation on the internet, it is part of a joke, but I was intrigued by how the video can be emulated with the colors and the curve proposed in the video.The video talks about neural networks, it will be a form of synaxis in our mathematically emulated brain?
(The video was longer but I cut it), any help to understand will be appreciated.

[Video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/155VMgraqDlo6t29npK-zyij7B9ukFR74/view?usp=sharing)